# How to use ansible nested variables in jinja2 with regular expressions and replace

Tags: replace, ansible, devops

I need to replace content in a variable in ansible. how would I do this?

I followed the below way but this did not work for me. the variable getting updated instead of value in variable.

```
- set_fact: var="{{temp | replace('instance', '{{value}}') | replace ('volume', '{{ebs}}')}}"
```

when I use the above code the variable values are not getting replaced. these are replacing like complete variable `{{value}} , {{ebs}}` as values.

I need the output like `- set_fact: var="{{temp | replace('instance', 'c4.micro') | replace ('volume', '20GB')}}"`

Comment: Don't use moustaches inside moustaches.
`set_fact: var="{{temp | replace('instance', value)...`

Comment: none of the above answers and duplicated question answer also not worked for me. I used the below syntax and It worked now. `- set_fact: var="{{temp | replace('instance', ''+value+'') | replace ('volume', ''+ebs+'')}}"`

Comment: Take off the empty strings and try again. `''+value+''` is just `value`.